# Magento 2 : Hide product from product page programmatically

Tags: magento2, product

I want to hide product from product page programmatically as like **I want to hide some product image when change dropdown from product page without page load.** checkbox checked in admin side.

How to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What specific data do you want to hide from product page ? image ?

Comment: I want to hide some product image when change dropdown from product page without page load.

Comment: are U talking about which dropdown?

Comment: I have dropdown attirbute & that attribute value display on product page. It's custom dropdown.

Comment: For ex : There are three value in dropdown A,B,C (It's testing attribute options). When I select A, then 2nd image from the image gallery should be hide from the product page. If I select B, then 1st image should be hide from product page gallery.